how to remove a user from json file
I wrote a Telegram bot with Python, and everything works except for the remove_user function. The bot operates like this: users start the bot, their usernames are captured, converted to IDs, and then stored in a JSON file.
Now, I created another function that allows me to remove a user from the saved list in case they mistakenly started the bot. However, when I run the /remove_user command, it doesn't send the messages I specified, it doesn't give any errors, and it doesn't delete the user.
Where is the problem?
here's the code:
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
import json

# File for storing user IDs
ID_FILE = "user_ids.json"
ADMINS = [my_userid]  # Enter admin IDs here

# Function to save IDs to a file
def save_ids(user_ids):
    with open(ID_FILE, "w") as f:
        json.dump(user_ids, f)

# Function to load IDs from a file
def load_ids():
    try:
        with open(ID_FILE, "r") as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []

# Start command
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if user_id in ADMINS:
        await update.message.reply_text("Welcome, dear admin!")  # Welcome message for admin
        return  # If admin, do nothing and just exit the function

    user_ids = load_ids()
    if user_id not in user_ids:
        user_ids.append(user_id)
        save_ids(user_ids)
        await update.message.reply_text("You have been added to the user list!")

# Command to list users
async def list_users(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if user_id not in ADMINS:
        await update.message.reply_text("You do not have the necessary permissions.")
        return

    user_ids = load_ids()
    usernames = []

    for user_id in user_ids:
        try:
            chat = await context.bot.get_chat(user_id)
            if chat.username:
                usernames.append(f"@{chat.username}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error getting username for {user_id}: {e}")

    if usernames:
        await update.message.reply_text("Registered users:\n" + "\n".join(usernames))
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("No users have registered.")

# Command to remove user
async def remove_user(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id

    # Check if the user is an admin
    if user_id not in ADMINS:
        await update.message.reply_text("You do not have the necessary permissions.")
        return

    # Check if the correct number of arguments is provided
    if len(context.args) != 1:
        await update.message.reply_text("Please enter the username of the user you want to remove.")
        return

    username = context.args[0].lstrip('@')  # Remove '@' from username
    user_ids = load_ids()  # Load user IDs from file

    try:
        chat = await context.bot.get_chat(username)  # Convert username to ID
        if chat.id in user_ids:
            user_ids.remove(chat.id)  # Remove ID from list
            save_ids(user_ids)  # Save updated IDs to file
            await update.message.reply_text(f"User @{username} has been successfully removed.")
        else:
            await update.message.reply_text(f"User @{username} does not exist in the list.")
    except Exception as e:
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Error removing user: {e}")
        print(f"Error removing user: {e}")  # Debugging output

# Function to send a message to all IDs
async def broadcast(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    message = " ".join(context.args)
    user_ids = load_ids()  # Load IDs from file

    for user_id in user_ids:
        try:
            await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending message to {user_id}: {e}")

    await update.message.reply_text("Message has been successfully sent to all users.")  # Confirmation message

# Bot initialization
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token("my_bot_token").build()
    
    # Bot commands
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("list_users", list_users))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("remove_user", remove_user))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("broadcast", broadcast))

    print("Bot is active!")
    application.run_polling()


I even tried removing the '@' from the beginning of the username and printing out the errors that the program gives, but I found that the program does not throw any errors at all. In fact, the code does not work correctly.

Add print() statements to the remove_user function to ensure it's running.
